# White corners always there when using border-radius

Tags: css

I want to put a black dom over a white background, and both have border-radius.
But there is a white space all the time at the corner. Why is that?

Here is the code:

```css
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <p class="inner">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zoosyuvq/1/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, adding:

```
.inner {
  margin:-1px;
}
```

Should resolve it. This will line the borders up so the rounding calculations work out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way.

```css
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  height: 50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <p class="inner">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually in my project the color of main ground and inner ground is different, so the radius is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with 5px border-radius at top corners.

```css
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:5px 5px 4px 4px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <p class="inner">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```